# installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement on UICollectionView in ViewController

Tags: swift3, uicollectionview

I want to implement reordering of collection view cells in a collection view inside a View Controller, but the moveItemAt method is not being called since I can't seem to access the installsStandardGestureForInteractiveMovement property of the CollectionViewController. 
I want to know if this property is exclusive to UICollectionViewController or I can somehow access it in UIViewController currently hosting it?